# Why am I getting an error importing os.walk in python2.7

Tags: python, linux, python-2.x, wlst

I need to recursively search directories/subdirectories on a Linux server for directories of specific names and retrieve the files within those specific directories. I have tried 2 approaches, one where I import os and call os.walk and another where I import walk from os. Code below:

```py
def getDeployedLibraries():
        serverConfig()
        path = 'somePath'
        deployments = cmo.getLibraries()
        print(divider)
        print("Library Deployments:" )
        print(divider)
        if deployments:
                deployedLibs = []
                stagedLibs = []
                archiveLibs = []
                for dep in deployments:
                        full_name = dep.getName()
                        path = dep.getAbsoluteSourcePath()
                        deployedLibs.append(path+full_name)
                for (dirpath, dirnames, files) in os.walk(path):
                        for name in dirnames:
                                if name != "shared-lib":
                                        dirnames.remove(name)
                        for file in files:
                                stagedLibs.append(file)
                for sLib in stagedLibs:
                        if sLib not in deployedLibs:
                                archiveLibs.append(sLib)
                f = open("filesToArchive.txt","w")
                f.write("\n".join(archiveLibs))
                f.close()
        else:
                deploymentsList.append("No deployments of this type installed.")
        domainConfig()
        return deploymentsList
```

When just importing os and calling os.walk I get the error that AttributeError: class 'org.python.modules.os' has no attribute 'walk' and when I import walk from os and just call os, I get the error 'ImportError: cannot import name walk'.

This script does connect to WLST so I thought that maybe I was getting a conflict but didn't find anything to indicate such.

Comment: This does not look like a Python error. It's javarish. Is this Jython?

Comment: @KlausD. As far as I understand, this is python. I'm new to any type of python coding but all the formatting and syntax I've been using looks to be python. I did a quick search for the differences which is what makes me believe that I'm just using python.

Comment: I did have some java imports but I tried removing those and any associated code to test and that had no effect.

Comment: How do you run your code?

Comment: I have a launcher that runs "java -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true weblogic.WLST /apps/config/scripts/test/libComparison.py"
Could the java part of that line be converting the code to jython? I admit I used that line because someone else had used that for their scripts.

Comment: or is all that just for wlst and doesn't affect whether my script is python or jython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function should be imported from `os.path`:

```py
from os.path import walk
```

Comment: `os.path.walk` and `os.walk` are two different functions.

Comment: WLST uses Python 2.2.1 and not 2.7. os.walk may not be available

Comment: Seriously!? It's from 2002!

Comment: So even though what I have installed is 2.7, since I'm also running WLST I can only use features from 2.2.1?

Comment: i'm afraid yes.
WLST embeds its own version of python.
Check it by running the sys.version command in WLST.

Comment: I did as instructed and the output was indeed 2.2.1 That's frustrating but at least I know now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: i agree. Its a big issue with Oracle's products. All th FusionMiddleware products use jython 2.2.1